# How do I separate values using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, import

How do I separate the values using Python? I've tried `split` and `linespace` but they don't split the data in the way I'm expecting

My .txt file contains the following:

```
{0: 'tench, Tinca tinca', 
1: 'goldfish, Carassius auratus', 
2: 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating carcharias', 3: 'tiger shark, Galeocerdo cuvieri', 
4: 'hammerhead, hammerhead shark', 
5: 'electric ray, crampfish, numbfish, torpedo',}
```

I'm looking for an output `key = [0,1,2,3,...]` `Values = ['tench, Tinca tinca','goldfish, Carassius auratus',...]` or can I just somehow convert it into a dictionary? I've tried split using the argument (',') and it splits 'tench, but I want 'tench, Tinca tinca' as an output.

This is the code I'm stuck on

```
f = open('imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.txt', 'r') 
x = f.read().lower().strip().split("',") 
y = [] 
for i in x: (y.append(i)) 
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

The key idea is to read the raw text as `dict`.

```
import ast
with open('imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    dicts = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(list(dicts.keys()))
print(list(dicts.values()))
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
['tench, Tinca tinca', 'goldfish, Carassius auratus', 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating carcharias', 'tiger shark, Galeocerdo cuvieri', 'hammerhead, hammerhead shark', 'electric ray, crampfish, numbfish, torpedo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack:

```
a = re.findall("(\d+): \'(.*?)\'", txt)
keys, values = zip(*a)
```

Other dirty hack:

```
txt = txt.replace("'", '"').replace(",}", "}")  
txt = re.sub("(\d+):", r'"\1":', txt)
data = json.loads(txt)
```

Of cource, you should import re or json respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change from str representation of the text file to dict, use:

```
str_to_dict = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

Once you have a dict, if I understand correctly, you want 1 list of all the keys and other list containing all the values. For that, you can do this:

```
keys = []
values = []
for key,val in str_to_dict.items():
   keys.append(key)
   values.append(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumming you can store the contents of the file in a `str`:

```py
text = "0: 'tench, Tinca tinca', 1: 'goldfish, Carassius auratus', 2: 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating carcharias', 3: 'tiger shark, Galeocerdo cuvieri', 4: 'hammerhead, hammerhead shark', 5: 'electric ray, crampfish, numbfish, torpedo',"

text_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, text.split("',")))
keys = list(map(lambda x: x.split(":")[0], text_list))
values = list(map(lambda x: x.split(":")[1][2:], text_list))
my_dict = dict(zip(keys,values))
```

Not the most elegant solution, but works if you don't want to use other packages as ast. However, I recommend you using the ast packages as described in the answers provided by other users as it can deal with different formats/spacing so you don't have to worry about that.